# cffile directory and upload works for some database variables but for some it doesn't

Tags: html, coldfusion

[image]I'm honestly not sure what is wrong with my code. I've been trying to figure out what is the problem for a couple hours now to no avail. Basically what I'm trying to do is upload a picture into a specific directory with it's Suite# as the filename. However, first I had to check a couple things:

1) Check if folder already exists. If it doesn't, create a new one with complex city variable and once it's created upload the picture with suite# as file name.
2) If the folder does exist. Simply upload the file into the corresponding complex city variables folder. I'm passing these two query strings parameters from a SQL query on my page.

Here is my code:

**HTML:**

```html
<form name="driverkeylistform" id="form" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="fileuploadtest.cfm?Suite=#getOrder.SuiteNum#&Ordernum=#getOrder.ORDERNUM#" method="post" onsubmit="return validateForm()">

<div class="row" id="submittedButtons">
 <input type="file" name="fileUpload" id="file" class="form-control-file" accept="image/*" capture="camera" required onchange="return fileValidation()">
 <input type="submit" name="dbAction" class="btn btn-primary" value="Done/Upload/Send Email">
</div>

</form>
```

**On processing page:**

I tried putting a cftry and catch statement to catch any errors and it gave me this error:

> Attribute validation error for tag CFFILE. Caught an exception, type =
>   Application

```
<!----Get Data---->
<cfquery name="communities" datasource="testData">
    SELECT DISTINCT
    [COMPLEX CITY] as COMPLEXCITY,
    [COMPLEX NAME] as COMPLEXNAME,
    [COMPLEX ST] as COMPLEXST,
    [ORDERNUM],
    [Suite##] AS SUITE
    FROM SCHEDULE
    WHERE SUITE = '#URL.Suite#'
    AND [ORDERNUM] = '#URL.Ordernum#'
</cfquery>

<cfset newFileName = #URL.Suite# />
<cfset defaultDirectory = "D:\uploads\" />
<cfset fileDestination = #communities.COMPLEXCITY# & "\" & #communities.COMPLEXNAME# & "\">

<!---Pull complex city and check to see if a folder is available in directory, if it is. Upload it into folder directory --->
<cftry>
<cfif directoryExists("#defaultDirectory##communities.COMPLEXCITY#")>
<cffile 
      action="upload" 
      accept="image/jpg, image/jpeg, image/png" 
      destination="#defaultDirectory##fileDestination#"
      nameconflict="makeunique" 
      filefield="form.fileUpload"
/>
<cfset sourcePath = #cffile.serverFileName# & "." & #cffile.serverFileExt# />
<cfset destinationPath = #newFileName# & "." & #cffile.serverFileExt# />
<cffile 
    action="rename" 
    source="#defaultDirectory##fileDestination##sourcePath#" 
    destination="#defaultDirectory##fileDestination##destinationPath#"
/>
<cfelse>
<!--- If it isn't, create folder of complex city variable, and upload it into that folder with file rename of Suite # as filename. --->
<cfdirectory
    action="create"
    directory="#defaultDirectory##fileDestination#"
>
<cffile 
      action="upload" 
      accept="image/jpg, image/jpeg, image/png" 
      destination="#defaultDirectory##fileDestination#"
      nameconflict="makeunique" 
      filefield="form.fileUpload"
/>
<cfset sourcePath = #cffile.serverFileName# & "." & #cffile.serverFileExt# />
<cfset destinationPath = #newFileName# & "." & #cffile.serverFileExt# />
<cffile 
    action="rename" 
    source="#defaultDirectory##fileDestination##sourcePath#" 
    destination="#defaultDirectory##fileDestination##destinationPath#"
/>
</cfif>
<cfcatch type="any">
    <cfoutput>
            <p>#cfcatch.message#</p> 
            <p>Caught an exception, type = #CFCATCH.TYPE#</p> 
    </cfoutput>
</cfcatch>
```

I should note: The file upload functionality works for some of the users. like for this example.:

[image]

But not for this and instead returns a 500 internal server error in which I started doing the cftry blocks.

[image]

Comment: Which of the two cffile calls fails?

Comment: I just noticed something. For some odd reason now the second order number 279137 isn't uploading any files whatsoever. I commented out all my code and just did a simple upload test and it's not uploading in the folder at all. The ordernum 228732 is uploading just fine however.

Comment: What is the line of code it fails on? Can you give us the full `<cfcatch>`?

Comment: I'm not sure to be honest. I'm still learning cftry and catch blocks. I'll see what I can do one second

Comment: Rather than do `cfcatch.message`, just do `cfcatch`.  Usually I'll do: `<cfdump var="#cfcatch#">` in the `<cfcatch>` block.

Comment: I added in the screenshot of the stacktrace

Comment: Have you checked your file system to see if the folder(s) is there?

Comment: Oh okay. By the way I don't see no folder for D:\uploads\Sunnyvale\Spruce Apartments\. However, I do see D:\uploads\Sunnyvale\anotherlocation. My other thought was maybe I didn't do logic to have more then 1 folder within another subfolder? Like if there are more then 2 folders within a complex city folder it results in an error.

Comment: The , is just the english version of the message.

Comment: Does the upload work for files with folders that already exist and folders that don't exist yet?

Comment: Okay I think i know what the problem is. I went into my file system and deleted the entire folder. Refreshed the page and it works now. that must mean there is something wrong with my else statement.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157307/discussion-between-snackboy-and-curious13).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per the chat:
The `<cfif directoryExists()>` needs to include full file destination, therefore `communities.COMPLEXNAME` needs to be added. I would recommend `<cfif directoryExists("#defaultDirectory##fileDestination#")>`.

Also, lines that refer to `serverFileName` and `serverFileExt` need to look at the client filename and should be updated to `clientFileName` and `clientFileExt`.